# How to modify the parameters of jmeter at runtime？ such as the number of thread pools

Tags: jmeter

I'm using the jmeter api to develop pressure testing tools，

How to modify the parameters of jmeter at runtime？ such as the number of thread pools，

ConstantThroughputTimer.throughput

[demo](https://bitbucket.org/blazemeter/jmeter-from-code/src/master/src/main/java/com/blazemeter/demo/JMeterFromScratch.java)

github,but not found answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the number of threads in the runtime (at least not with JMeter 5.5)

What you can do is to use [Constant Throughput Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-throughput) in combination with [Beanshell Server](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#beanshell_server) to control requests execution rate.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, is it possible to directly call Constant Throughput Timer in the form of api to adjust the speed instead of Beanshell Server? It would be better to have a code demo.

Comment: Thank you again. Start jmeter in the form of java code, which can be dynamically modified in the form of api

ConstantThroughputTimer. The throughput parameter does not need to use the beanshellserver.

Just call JMeterUtils. getJMeterProperties() setProperty("throughput", prop)

Answer (score 0):

I tried and found the answer by writing my own code. Parameters can be dynamically modified in the form of apis. Just call `JMeterUtils.getJMeterProperties().setProperty("throughput", prop)`。

ConstantThroughputTimer ：

```
ConstantThroughputTimer timer = new ConstantThroughputTimer();
    long rpsCalc = (long) (rps * 60);
    String paramStr = "${__P(throughput,50)}";
    timer.setProperty("calcMode", 2);
    StringProperty stringProperty = new StringProperty();
    stringProperty.setName("throughput");
    stringProperty.setValue(paramStr);
    timer.setProperty(stringProperty);
    timer.setEnabled(true);
    timer.setProperty(TestElement.TEST_CLASS, ConstantThroughputTimer.class.getName());
    timer.setProperty(TestElement.GUI_CLASS, TestBeanGUI.class.getName());
    return timer;
```